# Theres a way to know (debug or something like that) why not login?

Tags: cakephp

I need a simple Form authentication and my Auth components is like that

```
public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth'=> array(
            'loginRedirect'=> array(
                'controller'=> 'indicacoes'),
            'logoutRedirect'=> array(
                'controller'=> 'usuarios', 'action'=> 'login'),
            'loginAction'=> array(
                'controller'=> 'usuarios',
                'action'=> 'login'),
            'authenticate'=> array(
                'Form'=> array(
                    'userModel'=> 'Usuario',
                    'fields'=> array(
                        'username'=> 'email',
                        'password'=> 'senha')
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

i saved a user hashing like that:

```
$passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher(array('hashType' => 'sha256'));
                $this->request->data['Usuario']['senha'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                    $this->request->data['Usuario']['fake_password']
                );
```

The data is like that:
email: danielfpedro@gmail.com
senha: 95d3cddc86d8da996fb447d7faed12d560041ac23535a

the password "senha" in plain text is 123mudar.

I'm trying loging but is returning false And I have no idea why not.

Answer (score 0):

Will you check your database if what is the limit of the characters for password? Maybe the hashed password is longer than the length of the varchar yo had configured in your database. Try to make it to VARCHAR(500) for the password column.